# Как правильно запустить программу?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как стоит правильно запустить программу на обработку входящих сообщений с `WebSocket`? Будет ли достаточно такой функции или это в корне неправильно.

```
//класс с функцией start()
public void start(WebSocketClientHandler client) {
    while (client.getUserSession().isOpen()) {

    }
}

//основной класс с точкой входа public static void main()
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            final WebSocketClientHandler clientEndPoint = new WebSocketClientHandler(new URI("wss://example.com/ws"));
            clientEndPoint.start(clientEndPoint);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("InterruptedException exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.err.println("URISyntaxException exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```